# Shortcut - VS Code on MAC

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the shortcut for running code file in VScode? I cannot remember for the life of me

I tried Ctrl + shift + N and nothing happens

Comment: you can search the key bind GUI for `run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to re-install code runner and then the keyboard shortcut was 'ctrl, alt, N'